# google api vision обнаружить на картинке текст и перевести его

Tags: python, google-vision

Не смог накопать в документации нормальные примеры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю как сразу читать текст с картинки на русском (если на него надо переводить), но вот после считывания это вполне реализуется с помощью тех же google api

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from google.cloud import translate

translate_client = translate.Client()

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'some_photo.jpg')

with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)

def translate(text,target):
    returns_text=''
    for i in text:
        translation = translate_client.translate(i, target_language=target)
        returns_text+=translation['translatedText']
    return(returns_text)

def detect_document(image):
    response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
    document = response.full_text_annotation
    returns_text=[]
    for page in document.pages:
        for block in page.blocks:
            block_words = []
            for paragraph in block.paragraphs:
                block_words.extend(paragraph.words)

            block_symbols = []
            for word in block_words:
                block_symbols.extend(word.symbols)
                block_symbols.extend(' ')

            block_text = ''
            for symbol in block_symbols:
                if(type(symbol)==str): 
                    block_text = block_text + ' '
                else:
                    block_text = block_text + symbol.text
            returns_text.append(block_text)
    return(returns_text)


print(translate(detect_document(image), 'ru'))
```

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries